# Java Firebase get RealtimeDatabase value

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I try to get value like this:

```
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("positions");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Object userPosition = ds.getValue();
                System.out.println("abc " + userPosition);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
```

everything works fine but when I try to get value like this:

```
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("positions");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                UserPosition userPosition = ds.getValue(UserPosition.class);
                System.out.println("abc " + userPosition);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
```

I get no value (System.out.println() not displays at all).

UserPosition.class

```
public class UserPosition {
    private String currentMap;
    private boolean logged;
    private String login;
    private int x, y;


public String getCurrentMap() {
    return currentMap;
}

public void setCurrentMap(String currentMap) {
    this.currentMap = currentMap;
}

public boolean isLogged() {
    return logged;
}

public void setLogged(boolean logged) {
    this.logged = logged;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public UserPosition(String currentMap, boolean logged, String login, int x, int y) {
    this.login = login;
    this.currentMap = currentMap;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.logged = logged;
}
}
```

Why it happens and how to solve that?

If you need something more just ask. I do not know what else I should add because I cannot post my question.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your class does not have a default (NO argument constructor), you will need to provide that.**

According to official documentation, you need the following in order to be able to marshal the value into an Object of type .Class.

> public T getValue (Class valueType)
>
> This method is used to marshall the data contained in this snapshot
> into a class of your choosing. The class must fit 2 simple
> constraints:
>
> ```
> The class must have a default constructor that takes no arguments
> The class must define public getters for the properties to be assigned.
> Properties without a public getter will be set to their default value when an instance is deserialized
> ```

[image]